# Elasticsearch range with aggs

Tags: elasticsearch

i want average rating of every user document but is not working according to me.please check the code given below.

```
 curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/mentorz/users/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' 
  {"aggs" : {"avg_rating" : {"range" : {"field" : "rating","ranges" : [{ "from" : 3, "to" : 19 }]}}}}';
```

{ "_index" : "mentorz", "_type" : "users", "_id" : "555", "_source" : { "name" : "neeru", "user_id" : 555,"email_id" : "abc@gmail.com","followers" : 0,
   "following" : 0, "mentors" : 0, "mentees" : 0, "basic_info" : "api test info",
  "birth_date" : 1448451985397,"charge_price" : 0,"org" : "cz","located_in" : "noida", "position" : "sw developer", "exp" : 7, "video_bio_lres" : "test bio lres url normal signup","video_bio_hres" : "test bio hres url normal signup", "rating" : [ 5 ,4], "expertises" : [ 1, 4, 61, 62, 63 ] }
this is my user document,i want to filter only those users who have average rating range from 3 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

**Update Answer**

I've made a query using script, hope the below query works for you.

```
GET mentorz/users/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "term": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user.keyword",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "NAME": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "rating",
            "size": 10,
            "script": {
              "inline": "float var=0;float count=0;for(int i = 0; i < params['_source']['rating'].size();i++){var=var+params['_source']['rating'][i];count++;} float avg = var/count; if(avg>=4 && avg<=5) {avg}else{null}"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can change the range of your desired rating range by changing the if condition "**if(avg>=4 && avg<=5)**".

Comment: For example, if a user have rating as 3,4,3,5. So do you want to first find the average of all the rating that would be (3+4+3+5)/4 = 3.75. Then if the avg rating which is 3.75 in this case falls between 3 to 5, you need to filter that user documents. Is that what you want?